# jQuery button doesn't work with click, but works when added to alert box

Tags: jquery, html, button, event-handling, onclick

I have added a button on a html page to do some plotting.
The button to plot the figure correctly, but when I add an alert box to the code,  the click works as intended. Are there visible errors in my posted code?

How can I implement this to work correctly?

Here is part of the code:

```
// append to p container
pcontainer = $('<p></p>').append(button).appendTo('#plot');

//$('<input type="button" value="Plot Data" />').click(getData).appendTo('#plot');
// add all the variables}

/*
 * Download data for all the requested variables.
 */
function getData() {
    var baseUrl = document.getElementById('url').value;  // get the url address
    var x1,x2;
    var url = baseUrl + '.dods?';
    for (var i=0; i < document.variablesX.vx.length; i++) {
        var selectedX = $('#variablesX :radio').filter(':checked');

        //define the variables X that have been selected
        if (selectedX.length ==0) {
            alert("please choose ONE variable foraxisX");
            return;
        }

        var selectedY = $('#variablesY :radio').filter(':checked'); // define the variables Y that have been selected
        if (selectedY.length ==0) {
            alert("please choose ONE variable for axis Y"); return;
        }

        var selectedType = $('#myplot :radio').filter(':checked');  // define the plot type that have been selected
        if (selectedType.length ==0) {
            alert("please choose ONE plot type"); return;
        }

        if (document.variablesX.vx[i].checked) {
            // for each selected variable, get the data and pass to textarea.
            var url1 = url + document.variablesX.vx[i].id;
            loadData(url1, function(data) {
                x1 = toJsonString(data); //alert(x1);
            },  '/proxy/'); // load data from url1
        };

        if (document.variablesY.vy[i].checked) {
            // for each selected variable, get the data and pass to textarea.
            var url2 = url + document.variablesY.vy[i].id;
            loadData(url2, function(data) {
                x2 = toJsonString(data);}, '/proxy/'); // load data from url2
        };
    };

    //alert ("You have chosen to plot.");
    plotData(x1,x2);
}

function plotData(x1,x2) {
    var arr1, arr2; // define 1 dimentional array to get splited strings
    var d1 = []; // define array to put the two variables together
    arr1 = x1.split (",");
    arr2 = x2.split (","); // convert string into array

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i += 1)
        d1.push([arr1[i], arr2[i]]);  // combine two variables into one array

    // plot in flot
    $(function () {
        $.plot($("#placeholder"),[d1]);
    });
}
```

Are there visible errors in my code?
Can you help me implement what I described?

Comment: You're attaching your click handler to the p-element, not to your button. That's no explanation yet, but a possible source for unexpected behavior. For a more detailed examination, some markup and code context might be necessary.

Comment: I also tested the following code for the button, but it still doesn't work with the first click  // your button
    button = $('<input type="button" value="Plot Data" />').click(getData),
  // append to p container
    pcontainer = $('<p></p>').append(button).appendTo('#plot');

Comment: Hi, I have put the whole code for the plotting part, does any one have some idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code fro your getData() routine that gets the data from the server.

Assuming you are using an Ajax $.get (or similar), this is an async call and statements that follow it will be executed before the call to get the data has actually finished.  Either wrap the following statements in the success function for the ajax call, or get the data with async set to false.

Your alert is slowing the process down so that the get data has completed before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: Hi,thank you for your comment,but without the alert, the plot even doesn't work with twice click, it seems no data has been passed, not slowly actually, do you have some idea? Thanks!

Comment: Its still likely to be due to the ascync ajax calls.  Please post the code in loadData( )